# Validating a drop-down in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make sure that the user selects a value from the drop-down before submitting the form. Please have a look at my code below. What am i doing wrong ? Thanks

**View**

```
  @model Store.Models.StoreDTO
      List<Store.Models.CountryDTO> countriesList= ViewBag.Countries;
            var countryItems = new SelectList(countriesList, "CId", "CName");

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Countries.SingleOrDefault().CId, @countryItems )
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Countries.SingleOrDefault().CId) 

    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

**View-Model**

```
public class StoreDTO
{
public IEnumerable<CountryDTO> Countries { get; set;}
}

public class CountryDTO
{
    [DisplayName("CId")]
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Country")]
    public string CId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you included `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: yes. I will update my view-model shortly

Answer (score 1):

The following lambda expression is not supported by the helpers:

```
x => x.Countries.SingleOrDefault().CId
```

Only simply property access expressions are supported.

The correct way to do that is to define a Cid property on your view model that will hold the selected country Id from the dropdown:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("CId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Country")]
    public string CId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and then inside your view bind the dropdown to this scalar property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.CId, 
    new SelectList((IEnumerable<Store.Models.CountryDTO>)ViewBag.Countries, "CId", "CName"),
    "-- SELECT --"
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CId)
```

Comment: Thanks. will try that. Just to let you know that my Parent Viewmodel is called StoreDTO and Countries is a property of IEnumerable<CountryDTO> in StoreDTO.

Comment: I've updated my view model. Please have a look at it. How can i employ your method if my view is of type StoreDTO  ?

Comment: You could define a view model and then make your view strongly typed to this view model.